# Class object variable = none

Tags: python, class, class-variables

I'm trying to declare a class variable which should first be set as a database object in the get function. Then when changes are made, the post function should change an attribute of the class variable. When I set this up, I am getting errors depending on what I initially set the class variable as.

i.e. if I declare it as = None, I get a NoneType error. If I declare it as '1' I get that a 'str object has no attribute...' I tried as = object() and got the same message as the string...except for an object :)

example

```
class myClass():
   user = ???

   def get(self):
      self.user = database/memcache hit

   def post(self):
      self.user.name = self.request.get('name')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am stuck!

Comment: @DuhProgrammer13 There is no `null` in Python

Comment: Oh sorry my bad, thinking about java.

Comment: I think your `post` is getting triggered before `get` where you initialize `user`

Comment: Are you sure you want `user` to be class-level?

Comment: @thefourtheye How would post get triggered before get? Sorry - new to this.

Comment: @user2357112 is there a way to go about this without doing that? And without another database hit? I suppose it would just be a memcache hit... Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: @Mplax post will get triggered before get if some surrounding code does that. Without context, we can't tell you why. Please edit your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a *cached `property`*.

```
class myClass():
   def __init__(self):
       self._name = None

   def _user_get(self):
       if self._name is None:
          self._name = <get name from database>
       return self._name

   def _user_set(self, value):
       <set name to value in database>
       <if that succeeded then>
           self._name = value
       <or if you want it to be just re-fetched>
           self._name = None

   user = property(_user_get, _user_set)
```

Something like that but I'm sure that some one could provide an even more brief version.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it like this is generally a bad idea. When you instantiate your class, it is in an indeterminate state until you call `get` and fetch the actual user. What happens if you forget to `get` and call `post` right away?

```
m = MyClass()
m.post(...)   # AttributeError:....
```

You have two better options: either the initialize the class right away in the constructor:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, user_id):
        self.user = database.select(...user_id...)
        ...

# later on

obj = MyClass(1234)
```

or delegate the initialization to a factory method:

```
class MyClass():

    @classmethod
    def get_object(cls, user_id):
        user = database.select(...user_id...)
        return cls(user)

    def __init__(self, user):
        self.user = user
        ...

# later on

obj = MyClass.get_object(1234)
```

Either way, you'll get an object that is in a well-defined state and ready to work with.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern for more info.